# SFINAE template specialization matching rule

Tags: c++, sfinae, template-specialization

I'm learning about `SFINE` with class/struct template specialization and I'm a bit confused by the matching rule in a nuanced example.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct Foo{
    void foo(T t)
    {
        std::cout << "general";
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{
    void foo(T t)
    {
        std::cout << "specialized";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int>().foo(3);

    return 0;
}
```

This behaves as expected and prints out `specialized`, however if I change the specialized function slightly to the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type>
{
    void foo(T t)
    {
        std::cout << "specialized";
    }
};
```

then it prints out `general`. What's changed in the second implementation that makes it less 'specialized'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-focus your eyeballs a few lines higher, to this part:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct Foo{
```

This means that when this template gets invoked here:

```
Foo<int>().foo(3);
```

This ends up invoking the following template: `Foo<int, void>`. After all, that's what the 2nd template parameter is, by default.

The 2nd template parameter is not some trifle, minor detail that gets swept under the rug. When invoking a template all of its parameters must be specified or deduced. And if not, if they have a default value, that rescues the day.

SFINAE frequently takes advantage of default template parameters. Now, let's revisit your proposed template revision:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type>
```

The effect of this specialization is that the 2nd template parameter in the specialization is `int`, not `void`.

But `Foo<int>` is going to still use the default `void` for the 2nd template parameter because, well, that's the default value of the 2nd template parameter. So, only the general definition will match, and not any specialization.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that it's less specialized, it no longer matches the template instantiation. The second type parameter defaults to `void`, but since the `std::enable_if` now aliases `int`, the specialization no longer matches.